# How to build adb (Windows version) on a Mac

Tags: android, adb

After getting the latest Android Open Source Project (AOSP) source code and built it on a Mac, I get a Mac version of adb in /aosp/out/host/darwin-x86/bin/adb.  That's expected.

How can I build a Windows version of adb on a Mac?

Comment: Why do you need the windows version?

Comment: That hardly needs to be asked - obviously to support users who run windows.

Comment: @James  Because my software runs on both Windows and Mac and it requires adb to function.  So I need both Windows and Mac versions of adb.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question.  You can install the Android SDK for Mac [here](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r21.0.1-macosx.zip) and then add adb to your PATH.  Now you have adb on a mac.

Comment: @James  I want learn how to build adb from source since I may need to modify adb source code.  I think the Android SDK only comes with adb binaries.

Answer (score 1):

After Googling a little bit I found a GitHub project.  [This](https://github.com/karfield/adb) may work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It's somewhat helpful, but it doesn't answer the question of how to build a Windows version of adb.

Answer (score 1):

In the AOSP ,build the adb.exe steps:

1. source build/envsetup.sh
2. lunch
   `choice  **aosp_x86-eng** number`
3. make host_cross_adb -j16